# spark conversion from RowMatrix to CoordinateMatrix in scala

Tags: scala, matrix, apache-spark, distributed

I am trying to perform some operations in Distributed matrix space in Scala Spark, and I am wondering if there is any straightforward way to convert a distributed `RowMatrix` to a distributed `CoordinateMatrix`?

For example, if

```
rdd_input = Array[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = Array([10], [0], [0], [40])
```

The conversion of RowMatrix to 2 X 2 dense matrix was accomplished by,

```
rdd_input.zipWithIndex.groupBy{case (x, i) => i / 2}.map(_._2.map(_._1))
```

If the Matrix is sparse, how can I convert this matrix to a `CoordinateMatrix`?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since rows of the `RowMatrix` have no [_"meaningful (...) indices"_](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-data-types.html#rowmatrix) it doesn't really make sense to convert it to `CoordinateMatrix`.

Comment: Thanks zero33. It is true that RowMatrix does not have a meaningful indices, but I do know the indices in my case.

To rephrase, if my input is of form,
Array[Int] = Array(-1, -1, 0, 0)

The dense Matrix is 
[[-1,-1]
[0,0]]

The question was to parse and build this in to a CoordinateMatrix. 

Alternatively, can a IndexedRowMatrix be read into a CoordinateMatrix?